# How to check if contains array in c#?

Tags: c#

```
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
string[] arr2 = new string[] { "two", "three" };
```

I have to know if arr1 contains all string of arr2.

How to do it by coding faster?If there is a way by using lambda?

Thank you.

Comment: Can `arr1` have any duplicates in it (e.g. can `one` be there twice)? Can `arr2` have any duplicates in it (e.g. can `two` be there twice)?

Comment: What is the likely size of `arr1` and `arr2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Linq`.

```
arr2.All(x => arr1.Contains(x));
```

Comment: All of answer can do it,but I think this is the easiest way.Aha

Comment: You might want to use            
bool isSuperset = new HashSet<string>(arr1).IsSupersetOf(arr2);
for larger collections, it will run quicker.

Comment: @Sondre Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
var isSubset = arr2.Except(arr1).Any() == false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `linq` to solve your problem:

> Here  we check that if there is any element present in the child list(i.e `arr2`) which is not contained by the parent list(i.e `arr1`).If none such exists then the list is subse of the other

eg:

```
bool isSubset = !(arr2.Any(x => !arr1.Contains(x)));
```